# How to type-hint a factory class-method for pydantic GenericModel

Tags: python, generics, python-typing, pydantic, typing

I have the following class with a type-parameter, defined using pydantic's GenericModel.

```
from datetime import datetime
from typing import Generic, TypeVar
from pydantic import BaseModel
from pydantic.generics import GenericModel


T = TypeVar("T", bound=BaseModel)


class OcpiResponse(GenericModel, Generic[T]):
    data: T
    status_code: int
    status_message: str
    timestamp: str

    @classmethod
    def success(cls, data: Generic[T]):
        return cls(
            data=data,
            status_code=1000,
            status_message="Success",
            timestamp=datetime.now().isoformat()
        )
```

How do I add a return type to the `success` method in a way which captures the type-parameter? By which I mean the following should give an error/warning in the IDE:

```
class Test1(BaseModel):
    pass


class Test2(BaseModel):
    pass


def test() -> OcpiResponse[Test2]:
    return OcpiResponse.success(Test1())
```

I have tried:

- `Self[T]` (TypeError: typing.Self is not subscriptable). This would have seemed like the most logical syntax to me.
- `Self` (does not capture the type-parameter).
- `OcpiResponse[T]` (Unresolved reference 'OcpiResponse'). Although a non-classmethod typed this way doesn't actually give the warnings I would expect when there is a type mismatch.
- `cls[T]` (Unresolved reference 'cls').

Comment: type hinting aside, you may need the pydantic mypy plugin for this to work

Comment: It should most likely be `def success(cls, data: T) -> Self:`. You can `reveal_type` to check that `mypy` interprets this correctly (and it does, here's a [playground link](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.11&flags=strict&gist=0088c0b6815f889d2ac6bc8255acc7ac) with dataclasses instead of pydantic because it doesn't have pydantic installed)